# Python: convert datedelta to int value of time difference

Tags: python, datetime

I want to change time delta to integer value .

My code is as below.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.date.today()
print(now.toordinal()) # 736570
cali_date = datetime.data(2017, 6, 14)
print(cali_date.toordinal()) # 736494
date1 = now - cali_date
print(date1) # 76 days, 0:00:00
```

But, I want to get just `76` with integer.
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just reference the `days` attribute of the [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) you have there:

```
print(date1.days)
```

There are also `timedelta.seconds` and `timedelta.microseconds` attributes, modeling the complete delta state.

Comment: it doesn't work. It gives an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'. You should use a list iterator rather than using it directly. A rope thrown halfway isn't considered a help.

Comment: @skdhfgeq2134: If you have a `Series` object you don't have a `timedelta` object and this question doesn't match your situation. If you are using Pandas there are [dedicated types and methods for dealing with deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html).

Answer (score 10):

`date1` is a timedelta object  - use  `date1.days` to get the number of days as an integer, or `date1.total_seconds()` to see the number of seconds between the two datetime objects.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked using   `Serie.dt.days` . It changes the datatype of a Serie from "timedelta" to "int" and the time difference is presented in full days.

Comment: onvert time elte float 64 from sceitifc notion to int

Answer (score 0):

Just set a new variable:

```
date1 = now - cali_date
date_int = date1

print(type(date_int))
# <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the solutions above worked fully. After I made sure both of the dates had the datetime format, their difference now also has the datetime format. Afterwards using .days works as intended.

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(now) - pd.to_datetime(cali_date) 
print(date1) # 2179 days 00:00:00
date1  = date1.days 
print(date1) #2179
```